# context is showing error in Navigator.pushReplacement in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to push the router according to authentication stage in of google auth by this following code ,

```
void authenticationUser(FirebaseUser user){
      _repository.authenticateUser(user).then((isNewUser){
        if(isNewUser){
          _repository.addDataToDb(user).then((value){
            Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context){
                return HomeScreen();
              })
            )
          });
        }else{
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context){
                return HomeScreen();
              })
            );
        }
      });
      
  }
```

but Navigator.of(context) is showing error that context is not defined , any solutions please ? Thanks in advance .. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use method's `Context` like below try out this:-

```
void authenticationUser(FirebaseUser user,BuildContext context){
      _repository.authenticateUser(user).then((isNewUser){
        if(isNewUser){
          _repository.addDataToDb(user).then((value){
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
           context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => screen));
              })
            )
          });
        }else{
          Navigator.pushReplacement(
         context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => screen));
        }
      });
      
  }
```

Comment: like what are the more issues? can you please attach in your recent question ?